# Rails: How to create an array from checkboxes without a model and DB records?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I have a list of IDs and I want to create a form with a checkbox for each of them. If an ID is selected it should become part of an array. 
The array will be later used in a javascript, which is activated by a button.

Since I want to use only 1 button, the array should either update after each change in the checkboxes or the button should first submit the form of checkboxes and then calling the javascript which is using the submitted array from above.

Can I do all of this in a Rails view, and how, without using a model and DB records?

Comment: Cool. You could use `check_box_tag`, for example. Or plain html tags. You don't need to connect view and model. Have you tried something and got any problem?

Comment: I've tried check_box_tag , but I don't know how to collect all selected checkboxes and keep them in an array I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use name of your array of check boxes with square brackets. For example, if you want it to be `these_ids` put something like this in your view, inside `form_for` block (here I just generate five check boxes, but in your case you should as you wish and all of them should have attribute `name` each with `these_ids[]`):

```
...
<% [*1..5].each do |i| %>
 <%= check_box_tag 'these_ids[]', i %>
<% end %>
...
```

And when you submit form you will see in parameters:

```
Parameters: { ... "these_ids"=>["2", "5"] ... }
```

with those check boxes` ids that you were checked.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new - could you be more specific:
* 1. If I use form_for, am I not supposed to name a model?
* 2. Let's say I have an array of ids: '["123", "234", "345"]' How do I use them with the code you suggested?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `["123", "234", "345"].each do |i|` will help you.

Comment: How do I create the form_for without a model? I read about form_tag, isn't it what I am looking for? And, how do I pass it to the controller?

Comment: Thanks, solved it - used form_tag and submit_tag to pass it to the controller.